# Changing base interpreter in PyCharm to default path from Terminal

Tags: terminal, path, pycharm

When prompting `which python` in the terminal I get `/opt/anaconda3/bin/python` and with `python --version` I get that `Python 3.8.3`, so in the path `/opt/anaconda3/bin/python` the version installed is `3.8.3` and if I run `pip install any module` in the terminal I assume that this module will be installed in said directory.

When working in PyCharm per default the Python interpreter that is used is version 2.7 and when I try to change the base interpreter in the virtual env in the settings of PyCharm the path `/opt/anaconda3/bin/python` won't appear. How can I use the python version and the modules installed from `/opt/anaconda3/bin/python` in PyCharm?

[image]

Comment: Use the `...` button and click through the folders to manually select `/opt/anaconda3/bin/python`.

Comment: Base conda can not be used as a base interpreter for usual virtual environments, use conda environments instead.